# Setting a custom printer dpi

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm still stuck with this USB printer I have. The printer supports a print resolution of 203 dpi, but C# seems to be wanting to print it at 100, because the text is always so incredibly blurry.

How can I change the dpi in which the image and text is printed? I've read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printerresolutions?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) for the Printresolution class object, but it never really stated how to set a custom value. Can anyone help m with that?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the link just provide the resolutions the printer supports.
You have to loop overs `PrinterResolutions` to know exactly the `PrinterResolution` your printer supports.

But if the [`PrinterResolutionKind.High`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printerresolution.kind?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) doesn't output what you expect and that you still find the result blurry, you may provide a custom resolution.

If the printer supports the `PrinterResolutionKind.Custom` then you can provide X and Y properties on the [`PrinterResolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printerresolution?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) to define the 'dot per inch'. Values should probably be the same for X and Y, but I don't know. In your case select the `PrinterResolution` which has the `PrinterResolutionKind.Custom` and set X and Y values to 203.

Then you have to [combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) all the settings for the page you want to print.
I don't have tested, this is what I understand from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are directly writing to the printer DC, it uses the resolution of the printer. The 1/100in units are just the drawing units. Your problem is likely dithering. To avoid it, use one of the device fonts, download the desired font to the printer, or disable dithering:

[image]

Comment: I will definitely give that a shot. If that solves my problem it'll save me a lot of work. Most of these printers seem to only know a hand full of fonts, any others seems to cause issues. I should have provided some source code, but what I do is to print: I write all my information onto a winform panel, and send it as an image to the printer, which is why I didn't consider that solution, but I guess it's worth a shot after all.